# Change Bundle Product images based on option selection - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product-images, magento2.4, gallery-image, bundle-product

I'm looking for some custom solution for Bundle Products.
Where Product Gallery Images will populate according to the selection of the Bundle product Options

Our requirement: On Products Detail page (Base image, additional images and thumbnails will populate according to the selection of the Bundle product options)
Under Bundle product options (We have added simple products) so we just want that on selection of any option its related simple product's images will be appear on the Product Detail Page Image section (Base image, additional images and thumbnails - Just like in the case of Configurable Product's option selection)

Comment: Hey @sheri, have you got solution for this?

Comment: Yes i have manually populated the images based on option change.

Comment: can you share the code as answer below please.